# PHP SQLSRV - Full-Text Query Not Working When Parameterized

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

When I run the following query via PHP sqlsrv driver, no errors occur, but no rows are returned either... If I get rid of the question marks (supposed to be parameters) and insert keywords, then it returns rows just fine...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  MAX(i.ID) AS ID,
  i.ItemLookupCode,
  MAX(i.DepartmentID) AS DepartmentID,
  MAX(i.CategoryID) AS CategoryID,
  MAX(i.Quantity) AS Quantity,
  MAX(CAST(i.Notes AS varchar(max))) AS Notes,
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.Price, 1)) AS Price,
  MAX(i.SaleType) AS SaleType,
  MAX(i.SaleStartDate) AS SaleStartDate,
  MAX(i.SaleEndDate) AS SaleEndDate,
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.SalePrice, 1)) AS SalePrice,
  MAX(i.PictureName) AS PictureName,
  MAX(n.SpoofStock) AS SpoofStock,
  MAX(n.PAM_Brand) AS Brand

FROM Item AS i

LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable AS n
  ON i.ID = n.ItemID

WHERE CONTAINS(
  (i.ItemLookupCode, i.Notes, i.Description, i.ExtendedDescription),
  '? AND ?')

OR CONTAINS(
  (n.PAM_Brand, n.ManufacturerPartNumber, n.PAM_Keywords),
  '? AND ?')

AND ( i.WebItem = 1 AND i.Price > 0 )

GROUP BY i.ItemLookupCode

ORDER BY i.ItemLookupCode ASC
```

I've verified that my parameters array is correct... Below is my script:

```
require LIBRARY_PATH . "/connect-db.php";

$tsql = "SELECT DISTINCT
          MAX(i.ID) AS ID,
          i.ItemLookupCode,
          MAX(i.DepartmentID) AS DepartmentID,
          MAX(i.CategoryID) AS CategoryID,
          MAX(i.Quantity) AS Quantity,
          MAX(CAST(i.Notes AS varchar(max))) AS Notes,
          MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.Price, 1)) AS Price,
          MAX(i.SaleType) AS SaleType,
          MAX(i.SaleStartDate) AS SaleStartDate,
          MAX(i.SaleEndDate) AS SaleEndDate,
          MAX(CONVERT(varchar(30), i.SalePrice, 1)) AS SalePrice,
          MAX(i.PictureName) AS PictureName,
          MAX(n.SpoofStock) AS SpoofStock,
          MAX(n.PAM_Brand) AS Brand

        FROM Item AS i

        LEFT JOIN nitroasl_pamtable AS n
          ON i.ID = n.ItemID

        WHERE CONTAINS(
          (i.ItemLookupCode, i.Notes, i.Description, i.ExtendedDescription),
          '? AND ?')

        OR CONTAINS(
          (n.PAM_Brand, n.ManufacturerPartNumber, n.PAM_Keywords),
          '? AND ?')

        AND ( i.WebItem = 1 AND i.Price > 0 )

        GROUP BY i.ItemLookupCode

        ORDER BY i.ItemLookupCode ASC";

// Allows us to determine the number of rows returned
$cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $params, $cursorType );

if ( !$stmt )
{
  die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

if( sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ) )
{
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $results[] = $row;
  }
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt );

require LIBRARY_PATH . "/disconnect-db.php";
```

The parameters array looks like this for the above script:

```
Array
(
  [0] => displayport
  [1] => hdmi
  [2] => displayport
  [3] => hdmi
)
```

Please note, I do dynamically create strings that populate the `"?" AND "?"` based on how many keywords are parsed. I verified that the strings are correct, and the above reflects what they would produce.

SO, is this not a valid parameterized sqlsrv query?

Comment: You're not supposed to put quotes around the `?` in the query..

Comment: @Kenney - I did try without the quotes, no dice. Still returning 0 rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `CONTAINS` clause is what you should parameterize.

This part:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(
  (i.ItemLookupCode, i.Notes, i.Description, i.ExtendedDescription),
  '"?" AND "?"')

OR CONTAINS(
  (n.PAM_Brand, n.ManufacturerPartNumber, n.PAM_Keywords),
  '"?" AND "?"')
```

should be written like:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(
  (i.ItemLookupCode, i.Notes, i.Description, i.ExtendedDescription),
  ?)

OR CONTAINS(
  (n.PAM_Brand, n.ManufacturerPartNumber, n.PAM_Keywords),
  ?)
```

and, assuming your `$params` looked like this:

```
 $params = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

it should then look like:

```
 $params = [
   '"a" AND "b"', 
   '"c" AND "d"'
 ]
```

Comment: Right on buddy! Thank you for your help. Converting my parameters to this format fixed my problem!